# Create a web application using Spring framework for back-end but without using Spring MVC.s

Tags: spring, angular, reactjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to learn the Spring Framework and therefore I decided to make a web application using it, but I don't want to use Spring MVC as it still uses JSP. What all projects from Spring can be used if I want to have a UI which can be made using React / Angular and the backend is managed by Spring.

Comment: You need to do some R & D yourself before asking this type of question .

Answer (score 1):

You have to use REST API, and pass data to front-end JS framework via JSON.

Look here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Start with creating a simple Rest Controller with Spring Boot.

Then you have to choose your JavaScript framework (jQuery, Angular, React),
and make a HTTP request to URL typed in your `@RestController`.

You can achieve this by using AJAX method from your JS framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it will speed up your development

[Restful Web Service with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

by the way,if you want to use Angular/React+Spring Boot you can use JHipster, this tool will just do the basic setup for your Angular/React+Spring Boot application in couple of minutes,the website has a clear video tutorial you can use it will only take about 15 min approx

[Jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/)